# Rails 5.2, master.key, capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, credentials

Upgraded from rails 5.1 to 5.2, and implemented credentials instead of secrets. Works great in development mode, works in production mode locally.

It’s got me foxed why when I deploy using capistrano to the server, it makes the symlink to master.key, but fails every time. The symlink file links back to correct master.key, and has the correct permissions.

I get this

```
02 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.4 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile 
02 rake aborted! 
02 ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: 
02 ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage 
02 /www/mountain_penguins/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt’
```

and further down

```
02 Caused by: 
02 OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: key length too short
```

To me this looks like it’s not finding the master.key, but see no reason why. Any ideas?

Comment: I even tried using environment variables passed in by passenger

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a docker build on our CI, and discovered that my **master.key file was empty**.

In your capistrano deploy, see if you can cat out the master.key file contents, to see that if it is as you expect it to be.  You might need a custom task for this, but hopefully it resolves your problem.